# Python limiting array

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert some data from a text file (fields terminated by ";") to a table in MySQL using Python. Inserting one by one takes too long, so I decided to write a loop to insert a large block of rows at once, but not the whole file (no memory available for that). The table has 21 columns.

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

print(datetime.datetime.now())
with open("/backup/backup/backupDB/csv/file.txt", "r", encoding = "latin-1") as data:       
    dbconn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = "server", user = "user", password = "password", port = 3306
    )
    cur = dbconn.cursor(prepared = True)
    cur.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='schema' AND table_name='table'")
    iterColumn = cur.fetchall()
    columns = str(iterColumn).replace("(","").replace(",)","").replace("[","(").replace("]",")").replace("'","")
    next(data)
    cur = dbconn.cursor()
    block = 5000
    y = []
    try:
        while True:        
            for x in data:
                x = x.split(";")
                y.append(tuple(x))
                if len(y) == block:
                    break
            cur.executemany("insert ignore into schema.table " + columns + " values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", y)
            dbconn.commit()
            y=[]  
    except:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

The code above works, but it caps the insert to 60000 rows, exactly, although I have 210000+ in my file.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `except` block executing? If so, can you remove the try-except so you can see what error is being raised?

Comment: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement" - what does that mean?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `y` doesn't have the right number of values. But I would only expect this to happen either in the very first iteration of the while loop, or in the very last. So It's strange to me that you're getting to 60,000 before crashing.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your insight. One of the rows in the file (#63,398) was out of format